# Why is my :hover css attribute not working?

Tags: html, css, hover

I am making a website to hold all my projects, and I want an effect on where you hover over a Font awesome icon, it pulses in and out, however the :hover effect isn't working at all. Even trying to change the font-size doesn't work. I believe that something in the Font awesome sdk is overriding it, but there is every chance I'm just a fool.

```css
body {
    display: flex;
    height: 100vh;
    margin: 0;
}

.body-container {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.links i {
    font-size: 30px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    transition: transform 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

.links i:hover {
    animation: pulse 3s forwards;
}

@keyframes pulse {
    0% {
        transform: scale(1);
      }
      50% {
        transform: scale(1.2);
      }
      100% {
        transform: scale(1);
      }
}

.fade-in {
    animation: fadeInAnimation 2s forwards;
}

@keyframes fadeInAnimation {
    to {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Portfolio</title>
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/19a251552a.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="body-container fade-in">
        <div class="home-text fade-in">
            <h1>Damilola Owonibi</h1>
            <p>Front End Developer</p>
            <div class="links">
                <i class="fa-brands fa-github"></i>
                <i class="fa-brands fa-twitter"></i>
                <i class="fa-brands fa-facebook"></i>
                <i class="fa-brands fa-linkedin"></i>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="image-div fade-in">
            <img src="img/prof.png" id="image-div-pic" alt="">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="area" >
        <ul class="circles">
                <li></li>
                <li></li>
                <li></li>
                <li></li>
                <li></li>
                <li></li>
                <li></li>
                <li></li>
                <li></li>
                <li></li>
        </ul>
</div >
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Share the HTML markup too

Comment: Please read [ask]; in particular the part about providing a [mcve] (your code isn't minimal (there's **lots** of CSS that doesn't appear to be pertinent to the problem) or enough to reproduce the problem (there's no HTML at all). Stackoverflow has tools to provide an [inline live demo](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do).

Answer (score 1):

See [MDN on `transform`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform):

> Warning: Only transformable elements can be transformed. That is, all elements whose layout is governed by the CSS box model except for: non-replaced inline boxes, table-column boxes, and table-column-group boxes.

The `i` element is, by default, `display: inline` and thus generates a non-replaced inline box.

Comment: So does this mean I cannot use the hover attribute on i elements? As even trying to change the size of the i on hover doesnt work, it seams the i element isn't responding to the hover attribute.

Comment: That isn't even remotely what I mean (and I struggle to see how you could come to that conclusion based on what I wrote, which doesn't even mention `:hover`). The `:hover` pseudo-class (not an attribute) applies just fine to `i` elements. Please read what I said again. You can't use `transform` on elements that are `display: inline` which `i` elements are **by default**.

Comment: changing my animation to changing the font-size still doesnt seem to work

Comment: @DamilolaOwonibi — [font-size animates just fine here](https://jsbin.com/qifodeyuce/1/edit?html,css,output) (although I had to add some text to your italics for there to be anything to change the size of).

Comment: I've ran the code snippet here in stackoverflow and it works just fine, but running it in chrome or edge, it doesn't work.

Comment: Good news, i've figured it out. I didn't release all my css code as someone said it was too length, but i started commenting out things and I found out that the squares that I animated in the background are stopping the hover effect.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like things are working here, but there could issues in different browsers. Being that in `<i>` is an inline element, it could also cause issues. Give the `<i>` elements `display: inline-block;`. That should help. Additionally, if you want the item to really pulse, make sure to add infinite to the hover animation rule.

```css
body {
    display: flex;
    height: 100vh;
    margin: 0;
}

.body-container {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.links i {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 30px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    transition: transform 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

.links i:hover {
    animation: pulse 1s forwards infinite;
}

@keyframes pulse {
    0% {
        transform: scale(1);
      }
      50% {
        transform: scale(1.2);
      }
      100% {
        transform: scale(1);
      }
}

.fade-in {
    animation: fadeInAnimation 2s forwards;
}

@keyframes fadeInAnimation {
    to {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Portfolio</title>
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/19a251552a.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="body-container fade-in">
        <div class="home-text fade-in">
            <h1>Damilola Owonibi</h1>
            <p>Front End Developer</p>
            <div class="links">
                <i class="fa-brands fa-github"></i>
                <i class="fa-brands fa-twitter"></i>
                <i class="fa-brands fa-facebook"></i>
                <i class="fa-brands fa-linkedin"></i>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="image-div fade-in">
            <img src="img/prof.png" id="image-div-pic" alt="">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="area" >
        <ul class="circles">
                <li></li>
                <li></li>
                <li></li>
                <li></li>
                <li></li>
                <li></li>
                <li></li>
                <li></li>
                <li></li>
                <li></li>
        </ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i think my brower is actually just buggy, i ran the code snippet here on stackoverflow and it worked. I think imma just restart my computer.